# Create selector using a combination of variable and html element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

It it possible to combine a variable and a html element in order to create a selector?

Say, I have this variable:

```
var element = $('.myElement');
```

Is it possible to reuse this variable instead of doing this:

```
$('.myElement input').val('');
```

Something like... (which obviously doesn't work)

```
$(element 'input').val('');
```

Thanks.

Comment: Straight forward no because element contain reference to $('.myElement') & when you use it inside it become $($('.myElement') 'input') so incorrect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do it by using the `.find()`,

```
element.find('input').val('');
```

Please read [here](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to know more about `.find()`

---

As Mildly suggested, you could use the context feature of the selector too.

```
$('input', element)
```

Comment: There is no need to rewrap the element. `element.find()...` will work.

Comment: Exactly, or by passing it as a context, `$('input', element)`, which works just the same way.

Answer (score 2):

You could use optional context for your selector like `jQuery( selector [, context ] )`.

For example:

```
var element = $('.myElement');
var child = $('input', element);
```

[Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$(element + 'input').val('');
```

For more information about selectors:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

The `find()` function is very helpful when the 'input' element is not always available or selecting more elements, that you can loop through each item:

```
$(element).find('input').each(function() { /*some code*/ } );
```